# How to pass ControllerComponents in compile time injection

Tags: playframework-2.6

My controller is defined as follows

```
class UserController @Inject()(userRepo: Repository[UUID, User],cc:
    ControllerComponents)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends
    AbstractController(cc)
```

I want to inject `Repository[UUID, User]` into this component. I suppose I have to create an application loader and extend `BuiltInComponentsFromContext` and define my routes.

```
class AppComponents(context: Context) extends (context) with CassandraRepositoryComponents {

  lazy val applicationController = new controllers.UserController(userRepository)
  lazy val assets = new controllers.Assets(httpErrorHandler)

  override def router: Router = new Routes(
    httpErrorHandler,
    applicationController,
    assets
  )
}
```

My code isn't compiling because I have to pass a `ComponentController` while creating `UserController` in `lazy val applicationController = new controllers.UserController(userRepository)`. But I don't know from where to get this `ComponentController`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BuiltInComponentsFromContext` has instance of `ComponentController`

```
class AppComponents (context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
  with CassandraRepositoryComponents
  with HttpFiltersComponents
  with controllers.AssetsComponents
  with CSRFComponents{

  //TODOM - check if userRepository will be a singleton. Don't want new connection for each request.

  lazy val userRepositoryController = new controllers.UserController(userRepository, controllerComponents) //controllerComponents is defined in BuiltInComponentsFromContext

...
}
```